# Is there a way to formally describe the (complex) transformation $z\rightarrow\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The transformation $z\rightarrow\frac{1}{z}$ does what I can only (over $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ of course) describe as "turning space inside out" (then reflecting it in the real axis)

This doesn't seem like a very good way of explaining it, I can barely describe the idea of a plane being turned inside out if it has a tiny hole in the middle.

I'm sorry this is a bit of a null question, I can appreciate the transform but describing it as "turning space inside out" doesn't unambiguously convey what I mean.

Comment: If you view it as a mapping on the Riemann sphere, it's just a rotation about the $x$-axis. In the plane, it's the composition of the inversion in the unit circle with the reflection in the real line.

Comment: Maybe looking at it in coordinates would help: $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @user99680 I did, I "get" the transform, but I'd like to be able to describe what it does without saying "imagine turning it inside out" that was all.

Comment: @Alec Teal: Sorry, I thought the combination of reflecting :$x+iy \rightarrow x-iy $ and rescaling by dividing by $x^2+y^2$ described it, but maybe you already thought of this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry  where $1/\bar{z}$ is inversion in the standard unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

1. We can reflect a line around a point: $x\mapsto -x$.
2. The same can be done multiplicatively on half-line $(0,\infty)$: namely, $x\mapsto 1/x$. This is harder to visualize, but still possible: one can draw the graph of $1/x$, for example.
3. The transformation in 2 can be carried  out on every half-line emanating from the origin. This is the map $z\mapsto 1/\bar z$, a.k.a inversion in the unit circle.
4. The map $z\mapsto 1/z$ is the inversion followed by reflection in the real axis.